# PHP: Namespaces in a single file with a global namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a file that require()'s a namespace, as such:

```
<?php
require_once('Beer.php');   // This file contains the Beer namespace

$foo = new Beer\Carlsburg();
?>
```

I would like to put the Beer namespace directly in the same file, like this (unworking) example:

```
<?php
namespace Beer {
    class Carlsburg {}
}

$foo = new Beer\Carlsburg();
?>
```

However, the PHP interpreter complains that  `No code may exist outside of namespace`. I can therefore wrap `$foo` declaration in a namespace, but then I must also wrap Beer in that namespace to access it! Here is a working example of what I am trying to avoid:

```
<?php
namespace Main\Beer {
    class Carlsburg {}
}

namespace Main {
    $foo = new Beer\Carlsburg();
}
?>
```

Is there any way to include the code for the `Beer` namespace in the file, yet *not* wrap the `$foo` declaration in its own namespace (leave it in the global namespace)?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have Heineken as namespace!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the global namespace :

```
<?php
namespace Beer {
    class Carlsburg {}
}


namespace { // global code
    $foo = new Beer\Carlsburg();
}
?>
```

See here -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php

Comment: This wont work unless you write `$foo = new Main\Beer\Carlsburg();`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
namespace Beer {
  class Carlsburg {}
}

//global scope 
namespace {
  $foo = new Beer\Carlsburg();
}
```

As per example #3 in [Defining multiple namespaces in the same file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)

Answer (score 3):

Try placing a backslash before the namespace name:

```
$beer = new \Beer\Carlsberg();
```

The initial backslash is translated to "global namespace". If you do not put the leading backslash, the class name is translated to the current namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Just write it, it has no "name":

```
<?php
namespace Main\Beer {
    class Carlsburg {}
}

namespace {
    use Main\Beer;
    $foo = new Beer\Carlsburg();
}
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aYN6aI) and see [Defining multiple namespaces in the same file<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php).